# Error when theres zero ocurrence of word

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy

First of all, sorry for my broken english.

I’m using this code to count the number of times the words “LeBron” or “Curry” appear on tweets. The problem is that if none of the tweets contains the word “LeBron” or “Curry” the program crash. Is the words are there, the program run perfectly.

```
tweets_data_path = '/Users/HCruz/NetBeansProjects/elections3/data/fetched_tweets.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)

def word_in_text(word, text):
    word = word.lower()
    text = text.lower()
    match = re.search(word, text)
    if match:
        return True
        return False

tweets['LeBron'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('LeBron', tweet))
tweets['Curry'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('Curry', tweet))

LeBron = tweets['LeBron'].value_counts()[True]
Curry = tweets['Curry'].value_counts()[True]

print("LeBron %s" % LeBron)
print("Curry %s" % Curry)
```

When theres atleast one of each, "Curry" or "LeBron" I get this:

```
Processing...
LeBron 1
Curry 34
```

Thats perfect.

But if I remove "LeBron", so there are no LeBron occurrences, the program crash.

```
Hectors-iMac:src HCruz$ python process_tweets.py
Processing...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_tweets.py", line 80, in <module>
    s.run()
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sched.py", line 117, in run
action(*argument)
  File "process_tweets.py", line 54, in processing
    process_tweets()
  File "process_tweets.py", line 44, in process_tweets
LeBron = tweets['LeBron'].value_counts()[True]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 491, in __getitem__
result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1038, in get_value
return tslib.get_value_box(s, key)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 454, in pandas.tslib.get_value_box (pandas/tslib.c:9561)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 469, in pandas.tslib.get_value_box (pandas/tslib.c:9408)
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exception handling by surrounding the code on line 44 with try/catch:

```
try:
    LeBron = tweets['LeBron'].value_counts()[True]
except IndexError:
    LeBron = 0
```

Comment: Got an error but I change LeBron = None for LeBron = 0 and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out, Cheers!

Comment: If my answer helped you figure it out, please consider accepting it, thanks!